# Convert image based subtitle to text based subtitle inside MKV file

Tags: video, software-rec, ffmpeg, video-encoding, video-subtitles

How do I convert a hdmv_pgs_subtitle (which is image based) to a text based subtitle in a MKV file?

I have tried `ffmpeg -i in.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s mov_text out.mkv` but that results with the following error:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)  
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)  
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub) -> mov_text (native))  

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:2 - maybe incorrect > parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Converting image based subtitles to text is a nontrivial process, as you will need some kind of OCR system to interpret the bitmaps and figure out what the corresponding text is. `ffmpeg` alone will not do that for you.

I am not aware of any app that will do the whole process in one go, for Linux/UNIX. However, this process should work:

- Extract the subtitles with `mkvextract` or `ffmpeg`
- Convert the PGS subtitles to DVD SUB format with [BDSup2Sub](https://github.com/mjuhasz/BDSup2Sub)
- OCR the subtitles into SRT format with [VobSub2SRT](https://github.com/ruediger/VobSub2SRT)
- Mux the subtitles back into an mkv file with `mkvmerge` or `ffmpeg`

Comment: I can't find a build of any of the linked tools

Comment: Unfortunately it seems `bdnxml2srt` has vanished from the Internet. I've updated the answer with a different process (going through the DVD subtitle format instead) that should work. All the tools for that one are available.

Comment: Is this still current? there are command-line tools like subtitle edit now

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://subtitletools.com/convert-sup-to-srt-online) also seems to work as an online tool, but you have to wait a bit if there is a queue.

To extract the subtitles file, you can use this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -map 0:2 sub.sup
```